# How to contract product of curvature tensors?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I have a term of the form

$R_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}R^{\mu \nu}_{\lambda \kappa} (g^{\rho \sigma}g^{\lambda \kappa} -g^{\rho \lambda}g^{\sigma \kappa})$ which I would like to simplify, but I am obviously doing something **completely** wrong. My attempt:

$R_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}R^{\mu \nu}_{\lambda \kappa}g^{\rho \sigma}g^{\lambda \kappa} =R_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} g^{\rho \sigma}R^{\mu \nu}_{\lambda \kappa}g^{\lambda \kappa}=R_{\mu \nu \sigma}^{\sigma}R^{\mu \nu \kappa}_{\kappa}=R_{\mu \nu}R^{\mu \nu}$

Also

$-R_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}R^{\mu \nu}_{\lambda \kappa} g^{\rho \lambda}g^{\sigma \kappa}=- R_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}R_{\kappa}^{\mu \nu \rho}g^{\sigma\kappa}=- R_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}R^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$.

According to the text I am using, the first term vanishes because of antisymmetry of $R_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$ in the last two indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with the placement of the indices when you raise and lower indices of *nonsymmetric* tensors.

It should be $R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} g^{\rho\sigma} = R_{\mu\nu}{}^{\sigma}{}_{\sigma},$ which does *not* become the [Ricci tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Ricci_curvature), since that is given by contraction on the first and third indices, not the third and fourth indices. Instead it becomes zero because of the skew symmetry:
$$
R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} g^{\rho\sigma} 
= \{ \text{ skew symmetry of $R$ and symmetry of $g$ } \} \\
= (-R_{\mu\nu\sigma\rho}) (g^{\sigma\rho}) = \{ \text{ swap $\rho$ and $\sigma$ as dummy indices} \} \\
= -R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} g^{\rho\sigma}
$$
which implies $R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} g^{\rho\sigma} = 0.$